# close Eclipse editor if file is open twice

Tags: eclipse, plugins, duplicates, editor

I´m creating my own editor here for Eclipse and found a problem.
If I open a file and it´s already open, Eclipse opens a new editor.

So, I need to either avoid this or close the editor right after it´s opened.

My editor class is a child of MultiPageEditorPart and it has 2 tabs: first one is a Java editor and second one is a text editor. Java editor opens up a .java file and text editor opens up my own file.
I saw some posts saying about how to fix this, but I don´t implement IEditorInput interface anywhere here.

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks a lot

Here´s my editor definition:

```
    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
    <editor id="br.com.senior.wb.asas.editor.AsasEditor"
        class="br.com.senior.wb.asas.editor.AsasEditor"
        contributorClass="br.com.senior.wb.asas.editor.AsasEditorContributor"
        extensions="java, afm"
        icon="icons/editor_asas.png" name="Editor ASAS">
    </editor>
</extension>
```

Comment: It is not very clear what you are doing. What sort of file are you opening? Which editor opens? Which editor do you want to open?

Comment: Hi.
It´s a type of text file. The second editor is just a TextEditor.

If I try to open the .java twice, it works fine. But if I open the other file twice, it keeps creating new editors.

Comment: Show us how you have defined your editor with the `org.eclipse.ui.editors` extension point (edit the question to add this).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to open one editor when either the java or afm file is opened when the other file is already open then you need to use the matchingStrategy attribute of the editor definition to define an editor matching strategy.

Something like:

```xml
 <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
    <editor id="br.com.senior.wb.asas.editor.AsasEditor"
        class="br.com.senior.wb.asas.editor.AsasEditor"
        contributorClass="br.com.senior.wb.asas.editor.AsasEditorContributor"
        matchingStrategy="br.com.senior.wb.asas.editor.AsasEditorMatchingStrategy"
        extensions="java, afm"
        icon="icons/editor_asas.png" name="Editor ASAS">
    </editor>
</extension>
```

```java
public class AsasEditorMatchingStrategy implements IEditorMatchingStrategy
{ 
  public boolean matches(IEditorReference editorRef, IEditorInput input)
  {
    if (!(input instanceof IFileEditorInput))
      return false;

    IFile inputFile = (IFile)input.getAdapter(IFile.class);
    if (inputFile == null)
      return false;

    IFile currInputFile = (IFile)editorRef.getEditorInput().getAdapter(IFile.class);
    if (currInputFile == null)
      return false;

    if (!inputFile.getProject().equals(currInputFile.getProject()))
      return false;

    // TODO add more checks that 'inputFile' and 'currInputFile' are a matching pair of files
  }
```

Comment: It still really is not clear what you are doing. I am just guessing with this. Do some debugging. Is the matching strategy being called at all?

Comment: Yes. Strategy is called now after I created it.

Comment: Well then step through it and see what is happening

Comment: Problem here is that I need to open 2 files in my MultiPartEditor.
In my init method, I always call the super() using the IEditorInput for java file.
But if I use the EditorInput depending of the file opened, my editor opens the wrong file in each tab.

Comment: hi again, I posted more info about my editor here, but it was deleted, not sure why.
Maybe I can email you for more details and help about it?
Thanks a lot.